# Installing PECL Zip Extension

Tags: php, zip, pecl

I am trying to run this code

```
$files = array('readme.txt', 'test.html', 'image.gif');
$zip = new ZipFile;
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
readfile($zipname);
```

And realized I had to install the PECL zip entension, which I believe I did corectly as once it was comopleted, it added this to my phpinfo();

[image]

Even after installing this extension, I'm still getting this message.

**Fatal error: Class 'ZipFile' not found in**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

The class is called `ZipArchive`, not `ZipFile`.

Comment: Thank you, silly me, just overlooked that. Only other issue I'm having is after the zip file downloads on OS X and I try to unzip it, it comes up as **file.zip.cpgz** Am I doing something else wrong?


**Edit:** Figured out my issue, I wasn't specifying the correct location of _readfile($zipname)_